# How to create an unknown number of files with snakemake and use them in the next snakemake rule?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am doing metagenomics and am running into problems with my snakemake rule below.

My input file is a modified samtools coverage files containing sequence length, accession numbers and their taxon ids per row.

The rule has two goals:

1. Identify the accession number with the longest nuclotide sequences per taxid and write it to a text file
2. Identify all accession numbers assigned to the same taxid and write them to a text file

This is my rule:

```
rule extract_accessions:
    output:
        accession_with_longest_sequence_per_taxid="xy/relevant_accessions/{sample}_taxid_taxid_max_len.txt",
        accessions_per_taxid="xy/relevant_accessions/accessions_per_taxid/{sample}_taxid_taxid.txt",
    input:
        rules.generate_coverage_table.output.table,
    params:
        max_length_accession_out_path="xy/relevant_accessions/",
        acc_list_per_taxid_out_path="xy/relevant_accessions/accessions_per_taxid",
    conda: "python39"
    script:
        "~/map_accession_number_to_taxid.py"
```

`rule generate_coverage_table` creates a outputs like this: `bv00110_S1_R1R2_sorted_filtered.txt` where `bv00110_S1` corresponds to the sample name `{sample}`
`rule filter_by_mapQ` creates bam files like this: `bv00110_S1_R1R2_sorted_filtered.sam` (again `bv00110_S1` is the sample name `{sample}`)

When executing the workflow outputfiles are created as intended but  I get a **MissingOutputException**:

*Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in rule extract_accessions in file ~/snakefile, line 440:
Job 11  completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 5 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait:
xy/relevant_accessions/bv00120_S5_taxid_taxid_max_len.txt
xy/relevant_accessions/accessions_per_taxid/bv00120_S5_taxid_taxid.txt
Shutting down, this might take some time.*

Ths error is expected as the python script creates files where the second "taxid" is replaced by the actual taxon IDs found in the input file. However, I do neither know which taxon IDs will be found in the input, nor how many will be found. So, I also do not know how many files will be created previous to executing the rule.

In the next step of my workflow, I need to use the created files to extract alignments from a sam file. For this purpose, I need to know the output names (I guess, I would need to use the `{sample}` wildcard and somehow defne a new `{taxid}`wilcard.

```
rule extract_reads_from_sam:
        output: "z/{sample}/taxid_{taxid}_alignment_subset.bam",
        input: rules.extract_accessions.output.accessions_per_taxid
        conda samtools
        shell: """
               samtools view  -b <path_to_sam> $(cat {input}) > {output}
               """
```

I am not sure which filenames I should put into the output section of the rule extract_accessions. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you so much!

I tried to get rid of the error by replacing the content of output section by "xy/relevant_accessions/job.done". I let the python script create such a file and expected that the error disappears. However, snakemake threw the following error:
*Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'sample'*

Comment: You should look into [checkpoint](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution). If you also provide the format for the files {sample}_taxid_taxid_max_len.txt and {sample}_taxid_taxid.txt that would be helpful.

Comment: With checkpoints, the outputs are frequently [directories](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs) so you don't have to list all the output files explicitly.  When the checkpoint completes, you glob for the actual output file names.

Comment: thank you. I think checkpoints are the way to go!